# Http request with IIS node

Tags: node.js, http, iis, iisnode

Http request does not seem to work as it should with iisnode ... 
When I run this without running it under IIS work it just fine ...

Anyone know if I need to give any permission or something, or someone who has experience in general with http request to other domain using IIS Node.

I can unfortunately not show debug, since I have not gotten it to work real under IISNode.

```
var http = require('http');
var cached_defs = [];

function loadArticleDef() {

    var options = {
        host: 'http://someurl.com',
        path: '/data/DataObjectDef/GetDef?ArticeID=mypage'
    };

    callback = function(response) {
        response.on('data', function (chunk) {
            cached_defs.push(JSON.parse(chunk));
        });


        response.on('end', function () {
            console.log("end");
        });
    }

    http.request(options, callback).end(); 

}
```

Comment: I know this is old but did you ever figure this out?